# Display the different images for the annotation in mkMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Based on my different enum values, I need to display the different images in my mapview. 
How I can do that ? I am new to iOS development. Please anybody help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, your question as it stands now is not enough to help you. We expect at least an example where you attempted to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Extra info will help.

Comment: Generally, you need to use the viewForAnnotation delegate method as the answer says.  However, the answer is quite incomplete and inefficient.  In that delegate method, use the `annotation` parameter to check the enum value specific to the annotation and set the annotation view's image property accordingly (ie. just `annotationView.image = xxx;` using an _already_ resized image from the bundle).  There are several examples of implementing viewForAnnotation and setting an image.  Search for it (on Google or SO).

Comment: Thanks your comments helped me. And I can understand the answer after your explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "ViewForAnnotation" delegate method in your view Controller.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation
{
    if( [annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class] ] )
    {

        static NSString * AnnotationID = @"Annotation";

        Annotation * pannotation = (Annotation *)annotation;
        //if( pannotation == nil ) return nil;

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;

        annotationView = [self.mMapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationID];
        if( annotationView == nil )
        {           
            annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                              reuseIdentifier:AnnotationID] autorelease];

        }   


    UIImage * flagImage = nil;

    if(Your enum Values)
    flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkgreendot.png"];
    else if(....)
    flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangedot.png"];
    else
    flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluedot.png"];

    CGRect resizeRect;  
    resizeRect.size = flagImage.size;   
    resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
    [flagImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
    annotationView.image = resizedImage;

    return annotationView;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps you.